# Disable button in onClickListener inside ArrayAdapter

Tags: java, android

I have a custom ArrayAdapter, which inflates rows of a list into some text labels, and a button. However, I want to disable the button when the button is clicked.

So, here's what I have for example:

```
public class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Meetup> {

public MyListAdapter(Context context, int layoutResId, ArrayList<Meetup> elements) {
    ...
}

public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) { //need final int for mElements.get(position)
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(mLayoutResId, parent, false);

    Button statusButton = (Button) rowView.findViewById(R.id.statusButton);
    statusButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //what I want to do is this:
            statusButton.setEnabled(false);
        }
    });
}}
```

The problem is that I can't reach statusButton from inside the onClickListener.

The usual solution would be to make the statusButton global to the class, and that would fix my problem. However I'm not sure if doing that would link ALL the buttons inside that listView, and clicking one would disable all of them... Is that the case, or is there another solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per understanding of the question, disabling the button on click in pretty easy

```
statusButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //HERE is how you do it:
        v.setEnabled(false);
    }
});
```

Developer Android Reference here : [setEnabled(boolean)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setEnabled%28boolean%29)

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two solutions to your problem:

1. Declare `statusButton` as `final`.
2. Use the `View` sent to your `onClick()` method instead. This is the view which was clicked. In this case, it's the same as `statusButton`.

Answer (score -1):

You made your clicklistener an anonymous class.  You could change that by giving it a name:

```
statusButton.setOnClickListener(mActionMenuClick);
```

That way, you can later on disable by setting the clicklistener to null

```
statusButton.setOnClickListener(null);
```

and then re-enable by giving it the callback again